# How to i make domain authorization in Thycotic

Tags: python

I need some help on authorizing in Thycotic using current domain authorization via its API (no need to enter domain username and pass).
So the Thycotic API has this possibility, but i dont understand how to use it. In it manual i see some example, but using PS

```
$api = "https://<Secret Server URL>/winauthwebservices/api/v1"
$endpoint = "$api/secrets/8387"
$secret = Invoke-RestMethod $endpoint -UseDefaultCredentials
```

In my python script i'm trying with sspi

```
from requests_negotiate_sspi import HttpNegotiateAuth
site = 'https://<Secret Server URL>/SecretServer'
windows_auth_API = '/winauthwebservices/api/v1'
headers = {'Accept':'application/json', 'content-type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
```

how do i make the further login here? resp gives me 401: Unauthorized

```
resp = requests.post(site+windows_auth_API, headers=headers, auth=HttpNegotiateAuth)
```

Comment: its a local instance
ref https://docs.thycotic.com/secrets/current/api-scripting/rest-api-powershell-examples/index.md#windows_authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution

```
from requests_negotiate_sspi import HttpNegotiateAuth
import requests


site = 'https://<Secret Server URL>/SecretServer'
windows_auth_API = '/winauthwebservices/api/v1'
resp = requests.get(site+windows_auth_API+"/secrets/8387", auth=HttpNegotiateAuth())
```